# Ruby on Rails: Problem with Single Table Inheritance and has_and_belongs_to_many Relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations

I am in the way to designing the architecture of my system. For this, I have users with different roles. Given that I want the common behaviour given by Devise, I have decided to bet for Single Table Inheritance.

So , apart from normal users (usual customers) I will have editors.

Networks: Let's say it is like a fix structure in which content is displayed. You can think of these networks of screens with rotating content.

Editors: A subset of users in charge of posting content. Editors need to be pre-authorized (by an admin) to post content in specific networks. It could be many. But this doesn't mean every time a editor will post, it will be to all the networks he is authorized. In the end he gets to choose which networks will display a specific Event.

Events: A piece of content written for an Editor that might be displayed in all the networks the editor who writes it has access to.

In the end, testing with the console, I get this error:

```
irb(main):001:0> E = Editor.find_by_email("info@adeter.org")
  Editor Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."type" = $1 AND "users"."email" = $2 LIMIT $3  [["type", "Editor"], ["email", "info@adeter.org"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<Editor id: 3, email: "info@adeter.org", role: "editor", first_name: ni...
irb(main):002:0> E.networks
Traceback (most recent call last):
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column networks_users.editor_id does not exist)
LINE 1: ...works"."id" = "networks_users"."network_id" WHERE "networks_...
                                                             ^
irb(main):003:0>
```

I am in a point beyond my comfort zone here and I don't really know what I am doing. Is the initial planing wrong or am I doing something wrong?

Why can't I access relations?

**Editor.rb**

```
class Editor < User
  has_and_belongs_to_many :networks
end
```

**Event.rb**

```
class Event < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :editor
  has_and_belongs_to_many :network
  has_one_attached :image, dependent: :destroy
end
```

**Network.rb**

```
class Network < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user

  has_many :prospects, dependent: :destroy

  has_many :nodes, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :highlights, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :companies, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :promos, dependent: :destroy

  has_and_belongs_to_many :editors
  has_and_belongs_to_many :events

  has_one_attached :header, dependent: :destroy

  validates :name, presence: true, length:{ minimum: 3 }, uniqueness: true
  validates :user_id, :presence => true, :if => Proc.new { user.superadmin? }
end
```

**Extract from schema.rb**

```
  create_table "events", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.string "info"
    t.datetime "date_from"
    t.datetime "date_till"
    t.integer "version", default: 0
    t.bigint "user_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_events_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "events_networks", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "network_id", null: false
    t.bigint "event_id", null: false
    t.index ["event_id"], name: "index_events_networks_on_event_id"
    t.index ["network_id"], name: "index_events_networks_on_network_id"
  end


  create_table "networks", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.integer "number_of_highlights"
    t.integer "number_of_promos"
    t.boolean "open_to_request", default: false
    t.boolean "public", default: false
    t.integer "number_of_events"
    t.integer "time_between_slides"
    t.integer "time_delay_with_header"
    t.bigint "user_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_networks_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "networks_users", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "network_id", null: false
    t.bigint "user_id", null: false
    t.index ["network_id"], name: "index_networks_users_on_network_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.integer "role", default: 0
    t.string "first_name"
    t.string "last_name"
    t.date "birthdate"
    t.string "id_number"
    t.string "vat_number"
    t.string "vat_company_name"
    t.string "phone"
    t.string "address"
    t.integer "current_company_id"
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer "sign_in_count", default: 0, null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.string "type"
    t.integer "failed_attempts", default: 0, null: false
    t.datetime "locked_at"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end
```

Comment: I guess it has to be `has_and_belongs_to_many :networks` (plural) in your event.rb.

Comment: True. But the main problem is coming from editor's relation

Answer (score 0):

The thing was, that when using the inherited model, rails can't know from where is coming. The solution is specifying everything: Both foreign keys and the join table.

```
class Editor < User
  has_and_belongs_to_many :networks, join_table: "networks_users", foreign_key: 'user_id', association_foreign_key: 'network_id'
  ...
end
```

Now, it works.